# Missing Git Configuration Dot files

Tags: macos, git, vim, dotfiles

Earlier in the week I decided to try and turn all my dot files into a git repo using symlink and I broke a lot of my dev set up.  While I've restored what I can, I'm still having a few trailing issues that I'm unsure how to solve.

One example is when I run git commit (with no flags), it would normally pop up my vim with the typical items found in `.gitmessage`:

> 50-character subject line
>
> 72-character wrapped longer description. This should answer:
>
> - Why was this change necessary?
> - How does it address the problem?
> - Are there any side effects?
>
>   Include a link to the ticket, if any.

I apparently got rid of that file because when I run git commit it shows:

[image]

So I got one of the other developers here to send me their .gitmessage file, I dropped it into my directory but now when I run `git commit` vim just shows the normal vim start screen.  I start to type and save and it complains about not having a `filename`.  I give it one and it doesn't seem to care or attach it to my git commit.

I'm sure I screwed up a number of git issues but I'm unsure where or how to fix this.

## Edit:

Thanks to Michael I've updated my `commit.template` to point to the right file but alas I'm still not getting it right.  Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the `commit.template` configuration documented here? http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Comment: Hi @MichaelBerkowski - yes I am.  Is there a way to restore these files if I've moved/deleted them?

Comment: If you put the `.gitmessage` file back into place, it should be a matter of adding the correct config to your ~/.gitconfig or running `git config --global commit.template $HOME/.gitmessage`

Comment: Thanks again @MichaelBerkowski - I was able to do what you said but check out my edit.

Comment: damn. would it be worth reinstalling git? `brew reinstall git` - may be worth covering all of your tracks.

Comment: I notice you use `vi` on the command line which launches `vim`, but it's possible that makes a difference.  `git config --global core.editor vim`

Comment: oh. my. goodness.  That was it @MichaelBerkowski - thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: That be great, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of configurations went missing and they aren't difficult to restore. The first is the [`commit.template` Git configuration](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Basic-Client-Configuration).  Once you have restored your `~/.gitmessage` file to its intended location, tell Git how to find it with:

```
git config --global commit.template $HOME/.gitmessage
```

Or add if you don't mind modifying your `.gitconfig` directly, you can add:

```
[commit]
    template = ~/.gitmessage
```

Then, based on your animation above, it appears that Git may be using different editor settings than Vim as you expect it to. This may be because the `core.editor` configuration is unset and relying on your `$EDITOR` environment variable.  If you want it to use proper Vim (rather than something like vi compatibility), set the configuration:

```
git config --global core.editor vim
```

Or modify .gitconfig

```
[core]
    editor = vim
```

This part might have been avoided if your `$EDITOR` environment variable is set to `vim`.  I would recommend doing that anyway, so your preferred editor is always used when a running program calls for an editor.  In your `~/.bashrc` you may add:

```
export EDITOR=vim
```